# Logitech USB mouse/keyboard not working 20.04.3

Tags: 20.04, usb, keyboard, mouse

[USB error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzLsq.jpg)MB Gigabyte GA-970A-D3, AMD FX-4100, NVIDIA GTX1050Ti. Mouse and keyboard work fine using Win 10. Used ISO image to load 20.04.3 on new Hard Drive. I see error messages when the load process starts stating that the USB ports could not be started. This MB uses an Etron EJ168 chip for USB 1.1/2.0/3.0
I have seen several suggestions on Ask Ubuntu is hard to use them since the mouse and keyboard are not functional so can't get to the terminal. Help!

Comment: Since you do not give the actual error message but what you think it says I would guess its the USB ports not the devices that are having the issue.

Comment: I have no solution to the problem listed above. However, I installed Ubuntu-16.04.06-desktop-i386 and everything loaded and worked just fine. I guess there is something missing from the AMD x64 drivers in the latest versions.